# How can communication be done?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

There is something that is called XXXBean that has some logic that generates event. There is also some class that is called as ServletContextListener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>XXXServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

How can event from Bean can be sent to listener?

**Update.**

I have a Jetty WebSocket server that is running in the listener.

```
public class JettyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private Server server = null;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
            this.server = new Server();
            server.start();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        if (server != null) {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

This Jetty server should notifу remote client about events in the Bean though WebSocket connection.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am running Jetty server in the listener. If there is another way to go it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  `ServletContextListener`s are only informed of events about the context, i.e. when it is created and destroyed.  They are usually used to do some kind of intialisation.

Check the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html